# Anti-handwashing in the office

Tags: united-states, politics, covid-19

COVID finally appears to be winding down, so I was hopeful that all of the political drama at our office would die down.

Unfortunately, there is a new issue that has come up.  The group that was very vocally anti-mask and anti-vaccine, has taken a new stance: anti-handwashing.  Their arguments are basically:

- They can rely on their bodies natural immune system
- You don't know what all chemicals are in hand soap, and they don't want to put that into their bodies
- Choosing not to wash their hands is a personal decision and a personal freedom

I tried to stay away from all of this political controversy with the COVID vaccine/masks debate.  But honestly, I'm getting a little grossed out now.  I would talk to my boss about it, but my boss is one of the anti-handwashers.  Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135878/discussion-on-question-by-nomu--anti-handwashing-in-the-office).

Comment: Can you clarify whether they are opposed to any specifically anti-COVID extended handwashing rules, or just the regular, common sense "wash your hands after using the restroom" normal pre-COVID rules?

Comment: What kind of handwashing is meant here? Not washing hands all 10 minutes is different from not washing hands after going to the toilet.

Comment: Are you sure these people aren't making this up?

Answer (score 26):

Wash your own hands, do not shake hands with your boss/colleague (or do minimal fist/elbow bump); keep to yourself.

Think about quitting the toxic work environment before they fire you.

Hand washing is a personal hygiene issue that existed well before covid era.

Comment: Nice pun with the "toxic work environment".

Answer (score 2):

OK, I'll give you the benefit of the doubt and assume you're not trolling and that you're not being trolled (although I think there is a very high probability that someone in this situation is being trolled, I'm not sure if it's you who are being trolled by your coworkers or you who are trolling us with a ridiculous question, but someone is almost certainly being trolled here).

This is an actual workplace safety issue if people are refusing to wash their hands.  It doesn't really matter much in the actual workplace itself; I presume you have some sort of cleaning staff who cleans the offices (or at least the washrooms) with regularity.  The problem is, you don't know what your coworkers are doing outside of the office.  If the issue here is using hand soap, it's likely these coworkers are also not showering (body soap/body wash is much more chemically corrosive than hand soap), which means any germs they accumulate will continue to accumulate on their bodies over time.  For example, if they go to a seedy bar that doesn't clean properly, touch the washrooms there, don't shower, then come to work the next day, then you have that crud from that bar in your office, and nobody wants that.

Since you're in the USA, I can use the word "OSHA" when answering this question; this is specifically the type of situation that OSHA is intended to handle.  You should make a claim to HR on the basis of OSHA as this is a potential safety hazard.

Note that I would not do this on a single instance; if you simply see someone leave the washroom without washing their hands, that could be gross, but it's not an OSHA violation.  However, systemic lack of hygiene of a significant group of people in the workplace likely is one (IANAL) and should be reported to HR.

Comment: The problem here is I'm not sure how keen HR will be to take meaningful action. They'll probably throw up a "employees must wash hands" sign in the bathroom, not beyond that...

Comment: @GregoryCurrie You may be right, I don't know the laws in the USA.  That said, this is why I said I wouldn't do anything if it's a few people forgetting to wash their hands now and then, because in that case you'd be right.  If it's a significant number of people doing this in a systemic way, that could constitute a violation that would have the company legally liable, and HR's job is to not make the company legally liable for anything.

Comment: @Ertai87: I don't think OSHA would be keen to get involved in something like this. Without a legal system to back it up, hand washing is still only a recommended activity.

Comment: I knew a guy who, I heard, maintained that he didn't need to shower because his body's 'natural oils' kept him clean. I was told this by an ex-girlfriend of his. She was not with him for long. I asked how he smelled and she said 'rather like a wet dog'. She then told me that he had suggested that she wash her hair in her own urine, as that was also 'natural'. She left him, not because of these things, but because he was unfaithful. No accounting for taste.

Comment: There are OSHA standards requiring employers to make sure their employees wash their hands in certain circumstances (for example, if they come into contact with [bloodborne pathogens](https://www.osha.gov/laws-regs/regulations/standardnumber/1910/1910.1030) or they do [agricultural field work](https://www.osha.gov/laws-regs/regulations/standardnumber/1928/1928.110)) but it looks like in general there's just rules about ensuring adequate sanitation facilities exist. (There might be something that applies here but I couldn't find it.)

Comment: OSHA is not going to get involved with employees who don't want to wash their hands in an office.

Answer (score 1):

How about "Wash your hands and mind your business"? Unless you work in a place where there is a legal requirement to wash hands, who washes their hands and when is none of your business.

You didn't know who washed their hands before Covid, and it shouldn't matter to you now. You are the one making it a political controversy. Conduct your affairs in a clean, hygienic fashion and move on.

For the record: I'm a handwasher, and I behave as if I'm the only one. I can't (and won't) control other people, so I make sure my cleanliness is assured for myself.

Comment: It's clearly not the OP that is making this political. Clearly there are a bunch of anti-authoritians in the office that need a new windmill.

Comment: After visiting the toilet, there is an absolute requirement to wash your hands. Anyone not doing so is a filthy pig. You wouldn't be able to send that person to a customer. And I wouldn't want them to touch me or any of my office equipment, ever.

Comment: @gnasher729: I agree. That doesn't make it a requirement. If the company has a policy about it, then it's up to the company to enforce that policy.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie: There sure are, and the way OP is making it political is by getting involved. It has nothing to do with OP. Engaging in a pointless debate is what turns it political. It existed before Covid, and now all they're doing is identifying themselves (as gnasher729 put it) as filthy pigs.

Comment: @JoelEtherton I don't know how you can say it has nothing to do with them considering they have to share an office. The OP hasn't said they are engaging in a pointless debate at all. In fact, they clearly state they don't get involved.

Comment: @JoelEtherton And I think it's probably a false assumption that these people were anti-handwashing before.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie: Whether they were then or not is irrelevant. Handwashing has always been an issue in large company environments. This isn't a new thing even in the slightest. Now there's just a new fear attached to it as well a highly entitled section of people who think they can control other peoples' behavior. The harder they try, the worse it gets. The anti-vaxx, anti-mask, anti-handwash crowd is just a collection of trolls. You don't get rid of trolls by feeding them.

Comment: @JoelEtherton I'm not disagreeing at all. But you're the one claiming the OP is making this political, without any justification. The OP clearly does not get involved in politics.

Comment: @JoelEtherton I don't think these people are trolls either. They are doing this shit for political purposes. It's about seeing how far they can stick it to "the man".

Comment: @GregoryCurrie: you just defined a troll. QED

Comment: @JoelEtherton A troll does things to invoke a reaction. Sticking it to the man in this instance is about political power. They don't want to ever be controlled so they take these little symbolic victories as much as they can.

Comment: @JoelEtherton If you think all the anti-mask, anti-vaccine people are trolls just trying to agitate people, I think you've severely misunderstood them and their grievances.

Comment: @JoelEtherton Though I would say that some do get some enjoyment from causing distress to their political detractors.

Comment: why do you think restaurant restrooms have signs warning employees to wash their hands after using the restroom? Clearly some people don't, and it's only a law for food service workers. Yes, people are gross and always were. Move on.